# Выпадают элементы из флекс-контейнера

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

При правке чужой верстки вылез непонятный механизм в шапке сайта - всё на флексах, внутри контейнера-центровищика три элемента (один с маленьким логотипом, второй - пункты меню, третий - вход в личный кабинет). За счет auto-маргинов слева и справа у пунктов меню, лого и "вход прижимаются к краям. В сами пункты по-середине разведены фиксированными маргинами и при попытке перевести их на %-ые происходит следующее, - кнопка входа может при определенном сжатии просто наезжать на пункты меню, как будто их и нет, т.к. контейнер игнорирует всё, хотя всё должно сжиматься и места там еще хватает. Картинки с иллюстрацией изменений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
}

ul.header-menu.header-menu-center {
  margin: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.header-menu-right {
width: auto !important;
margin: 0px !important;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
}

header nav a {
  padding: 7px;
}

header.document-header,
.document-footer {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-nav ul.header-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-menu-center li {
  margin: 0px 70px;
}

img.nav-band {
  width: 45px;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 2px 20px;
}
```

```html
<header class="document-header">
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="site-band">
      <img class="nav-band" src="img/logo.png">
      <button class="toggle-menu btn"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-container">
      <ul class="header-menu header-menu-center">
        <li>
          <a class="active-link" href="/">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="" href="/company">Компания</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="" href="/shop">Магазин</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="" href="/necropolis">Некрополь</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="header-menu header-menu-right">
        <li>
          <a href="/login">Вход</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="header-menu-second" data-menu-item="company">
        <ul>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: добавь код?!!!!

Comment: Да, моя ошибка - добавил

Comment: когда я сжимаю, то кнопка входа просто проподает ни куда не лезит... не понятно в чем вопрос

Comment: Вот https://jsfiddle.net/bqyyv37c/ Когда поменяете фикс на %, то через инспектор кода гляньте, будет как на второй картинке - контейнер ужался, а контент вылетел